# Jenkins badge does not show when embedded in page served over http

Tags: google-chrome, http, https, cgihttpserver

I want to show Jenkins status badges on a locally hosted webpage served with CGIHTTPServer from python 2.7.

When I call the URL of the badge directly, it is shown correctly, but when embedded in the webpage, only a placeholder is shown. I assume this has to do with the page being served over HTTP, and the badge over HTTPS. In understand there would be problems if the page was HTTPS but the image HTTP, but this is exactly the other way around.

I am using chrome on Windows, if that is important for the answer.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

[Heads Up](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/) I realize that chrome has forced the pages to use https , except with domain .**local** , for example: **www.example.local**

then the first step: put the domain of your page : **.local**

second step: in /local/hosts put **www.example.local**

third step:  enter chrome and type www.example.local and ready

sorry my english , I hope I helped you

Comment: Nope I am accessing the local page directly via the IP, not some domain.dev. But interesting read! I understand that your linked blog post basically says chrome redirects .dev to HTTPS and thus can't be used for development (at least not as easily) when using chrome.